# cascading dropdownlist inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I know this question might sound a little bit off. I want to cascade `dropdownlist` inside `ng-repeat`. I have two `dropdownlist` A and B inside an `ng-repeat`. When A is selected, B is populated based on what is selected. If for example A is populated with types of fruits, when a particular fruit type is selected, all the fruits that belong to the selected type is populated in B.

Comment: I want to achieve this inside an ng-repeat.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: What is not working is that I cannot cascade inside ng-repeat

Comment: @uikrosoft Have you managed to find an answer to this by any chance? Here's my own SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683269/angularjs-cascading-selects-use-model-data-from-first-select

Comment: @adamj I have not. I will try your solution. Thanks

Comment: @uikrosoft Thank you very much on your reply. Please, could you let me know if you have any luck with it?